# Handling lower version database and higher version database in onUpgrade

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

I'm trying to upgrade database.

In onUpgrade function, 
1. extract favourite data from favourite table of database lower version;
2. save favourite data as query in "files/temp_favourite" (as file);
3. delete database lower version;
4. insert database higher version from asset folder;
5. read favourite data as query from "files/temp_favourite" (as file) and database.execSQL(query) in favourite table of database higher version;

I achieved 1,2,3. I got errors from 4 and can't proceed to 5.
Main Error: java.lang.IllegalStateException: getDatabase called recursively
Here is Logcat:

```
11-30 09:50:45.610: D/gralloc_goldfish(16127): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
11-30 09:51:03.950: D/dalvikvm(16127): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 164K, 8% free 3058K/3292K, paused 129ms, total 193ms
11-30 09:51:03.960: I/dalvikvm-heap(16127): Grow heap (frag case) to 3.656MB for 635812-byte allocation
11-30 09:51:04.280: D/dalvikvm(16127): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 10K, 7% free 3669K/3916K, paused 167ms, total 167ms
11-30 09:51:04.390: I/Choreographer(16127): Skipped 238 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-30 09:51:04.890: I/Choreographer(16127): Skipped 110 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-30 09:51:06.460: W/InputEventReceiver(16127): Attempted to finish an input event but the input event receiver has already been disposed.
11-30 09:51:20.830: I/createDatabase-dbExist:(16252): Database exists.
11-30 09:51:20.930: I/Databse Upgrade(16252): oldVersion=1,newVersion=2
11-30 09:51:20.930: I/Version(16252): higher version is found.
11-30 09:51:20.970: I/File(16252): favourite query file exprted.
11-30 09:51:20.970: I/File(16252): old database file deleted.
11-30 09:51:20.970: E/SQLiteLog(16252): (14) cannot open file at line 30191 of [00bb9c9ce4]
11-30 09:51:20.970: E/SQLiteLog(16252): (14) os_unix.c:30191: (2) open(/data/data/com.example.databaseupgrade/databases/Open3905Book) - 
11-30 09:51:20.990: E/SQLiteDatabase(16252): Failed to open database '/data/data/com.example.databaseupgrade/databases/Open3905Book'.
11-30 09:51:20.990: E/SQLiteDatabase(16252): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14): Could not open database
11-30 09:51:20.990: E/SQLiteDatabase(16252):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeOpen(Native Method)
11-30 09:51:20.990: E/SQLiteDatabase(16252):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:209)
11-30 09:51:20.990: E/SQLiteDatabase(16252):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:193)
11-30 09:51:20.990: E/SQLiteDatabase(16252):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.openConnectionLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:463)
11-30 09:51:20.990: E/SQLiteDatabase(16252):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:185)
11-30 09:51:20.990: E/SQLiteDatabase(16252):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:177)
11-30 09:51:20.990: E/SQLiteDatabase(16252):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openInner(SQLiteDatabase.java:804)
11-30 09:51:20.990: E/SQLiteDatabase(16252):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.open(SQLiteDatabase.java:789)
11-30 09:51:20.990: E/SQLiteDatabase(16252):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:694)
11-30 09:51:20.990: E/SQLiteDatabase(16252):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:669)
11-30 09:51:20.990: E/SQLiteDatabase(16252):    at com.example.databaseupgrade.util.DatabaseManager.checkDatabase(DatabaseManager.java:98)
11-30 09:51:20.990: E/SQLiteDatabase(16252):    at com.example.databaseupgrade.util.DatabaseManager.createDataBase(DatabaseManager.java:137)
11-30 09:51:20.990: E/SQLiteDatabase(16252):    at com.example.databaseupgrade.util.DatabaseManager.onUpgrade(DatabaseManager.java:69)
11-30 09:51:20.990: E/SQLiteDatabase(16252):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:257)
11-30 09:51:20.990: E/SQLiteDatabase(16252):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:164)
11-30 09:51:20.990: E/SQLiteDatabase(16252):    at com.example.databaseupgrade.impl.FavouriteServiceImpl.getFavourite(FavouriteServiceImpl.java:40)
11-30 09:51:20.990: E/SQLiteDatabase(16252):    at com.example.databaseupgrade.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:37)
11-30 09:51:20.990: E/SQLiteDatabase(16252):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5243)
11-30 09:51:20.990: E/SQLiteDatabase(16252):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
11-30 09:51:20.990: E/SQLiteDatabase(16252):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2140)
11-30 09:51:20.990: E/SQLiteDatabase(16252):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2226)
11-30 09:51:20.990: E/SQLiteDatabase(16252):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:135)
11-30 09:51:20.990: E/SQLiteDatabase(16252):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1397)
11-30 09:51:20.990: E/SQLiteDatabase(16252):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
11-30 09:51:20.990: E/SQLiteDatabase(16252):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-30 09:51:20.990: E/SQLiteDatabase(16252):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
11-30 09:51:20.990: E/SQLiteDatabase(16252):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-30 09:51:20.990: E/SQLiteDatabase(16252):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
11-30 09:51:20.990: E/SQLiteDatabase(16252):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
11-30 09:51:20.990: E/SQLiteDatabase(16252):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
11-30 09:51:20.990: E/SQLiteDatabase(16252):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-30 09:51:20.990: W/System.err(16252): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14): Could not open database
11-30 09:51:20.990: W/System.err(16252):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeOpen(Native Method)
11-30 09:51:20.990: W/System.err(16252):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:209)
11-30 09:51:21.000: W/System.err(16252):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:193)
11-30 09:51:21.000: W/System.err(16252):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.openConnectionLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:463)
11-30 09:51:21.000: W/System.err(16252):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:185)
11-30 09:51:21.000: W/System.err(16252):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:177)
11-30 09:51:21.000: W/System.err(16252):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openInner(SQLiteDatabase.java:804)
11-30 09:51:21.000: W/System.err(16252):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.open(SQLiteDatabase.java:789)
11-30 09:51:21.000: W/System.err(16252):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:694)
11-30 09:51:21.000: W/System.err(16252):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:669)
11-30 09:51:21.000: W/System.err(16252):    at com.example.databaseupgrade.util.DatabaseManager.checkDatabase(DatabaseManager.java:98)
11-30 09:51:21.000: W/System.err(16252):    at com.example.databaseupgrade.util.DatabaseManager.createDataBase(DatabaseManager.java:137)
11-30 09:51:21.000: W/System.err(16252):    at com.example.databaseupgrade.util.DatabaseManager.onUpgrade(DatabaseManager.java:69)
11-30 09:51:21.010: W/System.err(16252):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:257)
11-30 09:51:21.010: W/System.err(16252):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:164)
11-30 09:51:21.010: W/System.err(16252):    at com.example.databaseupgrade.impl.FavouriteServiceImpl.getFavourite(FavouriteServiceImpl.java:40)
11-30 09:51:21.010: W/System.err(16252):    at com.example.databaseupgrade.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:37)
11-30 09:51:21.010: W/System.err(16252):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5243)
11-30 09:51:21.010: W/System.err(16252):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
11-30 09:51:21.010: W/System.err(16252):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2140)
11-30 09:51:21.010: W/System.err(16252):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2226)
11-30 09:51:21.010: W/System.err(16252):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:135)
11-30 09:51:21.010: W/System.err(16252):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1397)
11-30 09:51:21.010: W/System.err(16252):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
11-30 09:51:21.010: W/System.err(16252):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-30 09:51:21.010: W/System.err(16252):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
11-30 09:51:21.010: W/System.err(16252):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-30 09:51:21.010: W/System.err(16252):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
11-30 09:51:21.010: W/System.err(16252):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
11-30 09:51:21.010: W/System.err(16252):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
11-30 09:51:21.010: W/System.err(16252):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-30 09:51:21.050: D/AndroidRuntime(16252): Shutting down VM
11-30 09:51:21.050: W/dalvikvm(16252): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb3a36b90)
11-30 09:51:21.070: E/AndroidRuntime(16252): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-30 09:51:21.070: E/AndroidRuntime(16252): Process: com.example.databaseupgrade, PID: 16252
11-30 09:51:21.070: E/AndroidRuntime(16252): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.databaseupgrade/com.example.databaseupgrade.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: getDatabase called recursively
11-30 09:51:21.070: E/AndroidRuntime(16252):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2176)
11-30 09:51:21.070: E/AndroidRuntime(16252):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2226)
11-30 09:51:21.070: E/AndroidRuntime(16252):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:135)
11-30 09:51:21.070: E/AndroidRuntime(16252):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1397)
11-30 09:51:21.070: E/AndroidRuntime(16252):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
11-30 09:51:21.070: E/AndroidRuntime(16252):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-30 09:51:21.070: E/AndroidRuntime(16252):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
11-30 09:51:21.070: E/AndroidRuntime(16252):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-30 09:51:21.070: E/AndroidRuntime(16252):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
11-30 09:51:21.070: E/AndroidRuntime(16252):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
11-30 09:51:21.070: E/AndroidRuntime(16252):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
11-30 09:51:21.070: E/AndroidRuntime(16252):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-30 09:51:21.070: E/AndroidRuntime(16252): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: getDatabase called recursively
11-30 09:51:21.070: E/AndroidRuntime(16252):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:204)
11-30 09:51:21.070: E/AndroidRuntime(16252):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:188)
11-30 09:51:21.070: E/AndroidRuntime(16252):    at com.example.databaseupgrade.util.DatabaseManager.createDataBase(DatabaseManager.java:143)
11-30 09:51:21.070: E/AndroidRuntime(16252):    at com.example.databaseupgrade.util.DatabaseManager.onUpgrade(DatabaseManager.java:69)
11-30 09:51:21.070: E/AndroidRuntime(16252):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:257)
11-30 09:51:21.070: E/AndroidRuntime(16252):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:164)
11-30 09:51:21.070: E/AndroidRuntime(16252):    at com.example.databaseupgrade.impl.FavouriteServiceImpl.getFavourite(FavouriteServiceImpl.java:40)
11-30 09:51:21.070: E/AndroidRuntime(16252):    at com.example.databaseupgrade.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:37)
11-30 09:51:21.070: E/AndroidRuntime(16252):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5243)
11-30 09:51:21.070: E/AndroidRuntime(16252):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
11-30 09:51:21.070: E/AndroidRuntime(16252):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2140)
11-30 09:51:21.070: E/AndroidRuntime(16252):    ... 11 more
```

Here is DatabaseManager.java:

```
package com.example.databaseupgrade.util;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.text.DateFormatSymbols;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.List;

import com.example.databaseupgrade.doa.FavouriteService;
import com.example.databaseupgrade.domain.Favourite;
import com.example.databaseupgrade.impl.FavouriteServiceImpl;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class DatabaseManager extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final String DATABASE_PATH = "/data/data/com.example.databaseupgrade/databases/";
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Open3905Book";
    private static final String CACHE_NAME="temp_favourite";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;
    private static final int SPLIT_NUMBER = 6;
    private final Context context;

    public DatabaseManager(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
        Log.i("onCreate:", "true");
        try {
            createDataBase();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        Log.i("Databse Upgrade", "oldVersion=" + oldVersion + ",newVersion="
                + newVersion);
        if (newVersion > oldVersion) {
            Log.i("Version", "higher version is found.");

            exportFavourite(db);
            Log.i("File","favourite query file exprted.");

            File file=new File(DATABASE_PATH+DATABASE_NAME);
            file.delete();

            Log.i("File", "old database file deleted.");

            try {
                createDataBase();
                Log.i("Database", "created new database.");

            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

//          try {
//              importFavourite(db);
//              Log.i("File", "favourite query file imported.");
//          } catch (SQLiteException e) {
//              // TODO Auto-generated catch block
//              e.printStackTrace();
//          } catch (IOException e) {
//              // TODO Auto-generated catch block
//              e.printStackTrace();
//          }
        } else {
            Log.i("Version", "lower version is found.");
        }

    }

    public boolean checkDatabase() {

        SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;
        try {
            String fullPath = DATABASE_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
            checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(fullPath, null,
                    SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

        } catch (SQLiteException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (checkDB != null) {

            checkDB.close();

        }

        return checkDB != null ? true : false;
    }


    private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {
        File DBFile = new File(DATABASE_PATH, DATABASE_NAME);
        AssetManager am = context.getAssets();
        OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(DBFile);
        DBFile.createNewFile();
        byte[] b = new byte[1024];
        int i, r;
        String[] Files = am.list("");
        Arrays.sort(Files);
        for (i = 1; i < SPLIT_NUMBER + 1; i++) {
            String fn = String.format("%d.bible", i);
            if (Arrays.binarySearch(Files, fn) < 0)
                break;
            InputStream is = am.open(fn);
            while ((r = is.read(b)) != -1)
                os.write(b, 0, r);
            is.close();
        }
        os.close();
    }

    public void createDataBase() throws IOException {
        boolean dbExist = checkDatabase();
        if (dbExist) {
            // do nothing - database already exist
            Log.i("createDatabase-dbExist:", "Database exists.");

        } else {
            this.getReadableDatabase();
            try {
                copyDataBase();
                Log.i("createDatabase-copyDatabase:", "Copying database.");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.w("Error-createDatabase-copyDatabase:",
                        "Error copying database");
                throw new Error("Error copying database");
            }
        }
    }


    private void exportFavourite(SQLiteDatabase db) throws SQLiteException {
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM favourite ORDER BY id DESC";
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(sql, null);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                String scripture=cursor.getString(1);
                int bible_id=Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(2));
                String query="INSERT INTO favourite(scripture,bible_id,datetime) VALUES(\""+scripture+"\","+bible_id+",\""+getDateAndTime()+"\");";
                try {
                    setQuerytoFile(query);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
    }

    private void importFavourite(SQLiteDatabase db)throws SQLiteException, IOException{
        String sql=getQueryfromFile();
        db.execSQL(sql);
    }
    public void setQuerytoFile(String str) throws IOException {
        FileOutputStream outputStream;
        try {
          outputStream = context.openFileOutput(CACHE_NAME, Context.MODE_APPEND);
          outputStream.write(str.getBytes());
          outputStream.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public String getQueryfromFile() throws IOException{
        FileInputStream inputStream;
        String line = null;
        try{
            inputStream=context.openFileInput(CACHE_NAME);
            InputStreamReader isr=new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
            BufferedReader buffer=new BufferedReader(isr);
            StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
            while((line=buffer.readLine())!=null){
                sb.append(line);
            }

        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return line;
    }

    public String getDateAndTime(){
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        String str=c.get(Calendar.HOUR)+":"+c.get(Calendar.MINUTE)+" ";
        if(c.get(Calendar.AM_PM)==0){
            str+="AM ";
        }else{
            str+="PM ";
        }
        str+=c.get(Calendar.DATE);

        String month="";
        int num=c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        DateFormatSymbols dfs = new DateFormatSymbols();
        String[] months = dfs.getMonths();
        if (num >= 0 && num <= 11 ) {
               month = months[num];
        }
        str+=month+" "+c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        return str;
    }

}
```

What's the solution to achieve 4 OR 4 and 5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SQLiteOpenHelper` assumes that you have a single database file whose contents you want to preserve.

While `onUpgrade` is running, the database is open, and a transaction is active.
You cannot replace the database file in `onUpgrade`.

If you want to use `SQLiteOpenHelper`, you have to do the upgrade by executing SQL statements.

Answer (score 0):

**Do not attempt to delete the database file in `onUpgrade()`**

instead use the drop table sql command to delete all tables

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table_name
```

That is:

```
db.execSql( "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table_name" );
```

for every table in your database.